# Margin: 0 auto; not working image

Tags: html, css

So I have this code, trying to center an image when the screen is a certain size and below, but it isn't working. It isn't changing position at all.

[image: Screenshot:]

```
#navbar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 55px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #3399FF;
}
#navbar_logo {
    margin: 0 0 0 150px;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
#navbar_links {
    margin: 0 0 0 250px;
    padding: 0;
    height: 55px;
    width: 430px;
    float: left;
}
#navbar_links a {
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 730px){
    #navbar {
        height: 110px;
    }
    #navbar_logo {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #navbar_links {
        margin: 0 0 0 50px;
        width: 430;

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML? The screenshot is kinda not enough. Perhaps a pen or a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating the element will push it to the side even if it has auto margins.

You need to explicitly set `float` back to `none`.

Answer (score 0):

Give `text-align:center;` to image parent's tag